# Android service that doesn't close with application

Tags: android, service

I have been searching the net for hours.  I am trying to make an application that has a UI interface and a service running in the background for SIP phone communication, kind of like Skype.

The UI starts and stops the service based on UI events, and the service stays logged in with a internet server in the background.  I have found many articles talking about running the service on a separate thread(done), using startService as opposed to binding the service(done) but whenever I use the task manager to kill the application as a user might, I get an error popup saying my application has crashed and the service no longer runs.

How do programs like Skype, Facebook, or email clients do this?

Do I have to run these as separate applications using implicit intents?

Is there some settings I have to set in the manifest file other than declaring the service and it's name?

Better yet, is there a link to some page or source example using this kind of service?

EDIT: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear.  The service is stopping, and I don't want it to.  I am trying to keep the service running in the background even after a user kills the application with the application manager.

Comment: Try killing the service in `onPause`, `onStop`, or `onDestroy`

Comment: See my answer below.  I would look hard at your design if you are having to force kill the UI but keep the `Service` running then there's a deeper problem.  If you *really* *really* need to separate your `Service` and `Activity` in separate process space it can be done, but it is abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more confusing things with `Service` is that it is *not* run in a separate thread by default.  Calling `startService()` as opposed to `bindService()` makes no difference in this regard.  However, the binder mechanism will cause the `Service` exposed methods to be called in arbitrary thread context.  In both cases, your `Service` is part of your application's process.  If you kill it via the task manager or it crashes then the `Service` dies as well.

When you kill the app via the task manager and it pops up the message about the app dying, you have something misbehaving.  Check logcat and it will point you at exactly where the crash happened.

If you need to have your `Service` running regardless of the UI, then don't stop the `Service` when your UI exits.  You will still call `startService()` when your UI starts to re-connect (and possibly re-start it), but don't stop it unless you really want it stopped.  Starts do not "stack".  If something calls start 5x it doesn't take 5 stops to terminate the `Service`, only 1.